# How can I enable volume control in my App?

Tags: java, android

My app is simply built as a simple web browser.
So main part is completely just webview.

When it plays youtube on the page, it won't allow me to turn the volume up even if i hit hard key.
It obviously doesn't show the volume slider, either.

How can I enable that?  I tried to add this below

To Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

To MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on this, but you might need to set the VolumeControlStream in the activity that's actually playing the audio, which might not be your MainActivity

Comment: Do I need to code whole part for all the key pressing? or does it automatically handle if I add few lines?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't need any code handling the actual volume key press events, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Then how can I enable doing it?